# regex matches repeating group {0,2} or {0,4} but {0,3} doesn't

Tags: regex, pcre

first, this is using preg.

String I'm trying to match:

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b c d xp
```

My regex and their matches:

```
(\S*\s*){0,1}\S*p = "d xp"
(\S*\s*){0,2}\S*p = "c d xp"
(\S*\s*){0,3}\S*p = NO MATCH (expecting "b c d xp"
(\S*\s*){0,4}\S*p = entire string
(\S*\s*){0,5}\S*p = entire string
```

Oddly, if I remove a single "a" it works.  Also, `(\S*\s*){0,3}\Sp` or `(\S*\s){0,3}\S*p` both work.

Can someone explain why the third case results in no matches instead of "b c d xp"?

TIA!

Comment: `m/(\S*\s*){0,3}\S*p/` works on your test string in http://regex.powertoy.org...

Comment: BTW... any specific need to use `*` and not `+`?  I get the same matches you are looking for with a lot less probes?  For example `m/(\S+\s+){0,3}\S+p/` matches `b c d xp` in 3081 probes while `m/(\S*\s*){0,3}\S*p/` produces the same match in 1200222 probes!

Comment: I would report this as a bug. It matches on PCRE (version 7.8), but does not match in my PHP 5.2.6 or 5.3.0 (which uses PCRE for its preg_ matching functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preg_last_error()` returns PREG_BACKTRACK_LIMIT_ERROR, so increasing backtrack limit should probably fix the issue. Try

```
 ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit', 500000);
```

Comment: awesome.  Thank you very much!  this was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 7):

Good question.

I tried another language that also has Perl RE syntax, Ruby, and it returned the expected string:

```
$ irb
>> s='aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b c d xp'
=> "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa b c d xp"
>> s[/(\S*\s*){0,3}\S*p/]
=> "b c d xp"
```

This made me think you found an interpreter bug...

But  we now know that

- Your RE was correct, as was your expectation of its results
- PHP has a limit on backtracks, and the problem was your expression hit the limit. Ruby just doesn't check, or has a different limit.